# Links aren't generating

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and I can't get my links to generate. The next button is supposed to light up followed by a bit of text.

How it's supposed to work: http://jsfiddle.net/zMQcn/

The one that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Yq8Qf/

```
document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';\">other 8b white</input>";
        }
```

Comment: It seems to me that neither one of them works?

Comment: `onClick` in option won`t work use instead `onChange` in `<select>`

Comment: there are many problems.... 1) the `tryToMakeLink` is a private method in the load callback so it is not available in the global context. 2) `option` elements onclick is not widely supported use `select`s `onchange` instead` 3) `:selected` is not a valid css selector... look like you are trying to mix jQuery selectors with native javascript

Comment: `<input>` is a closed element - if you want it to display text use the `value` attribute

Comment: also id of an element must be unique... so you have multiple elements with the same id `navlist`... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aYL8b/1/

Comment: @aldanux I changed it and still nothing http://jsfiddle.net/aYL8b/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comments above

```
<form name="quiz" id='quiz'>
     <h4>What carrier do you have?</h4>

    <select style="margin-top: 1pt" onchange="tryToMakeLink()" name="q1">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected>Choose your model</option>
        <option value="AT&T">AT&T</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
        <option value="Unlocked">Unlocked</option>
    </select>
     <h4>What is your phones capicity?</h4>

    <select style="margin-top: 1pt" onchange="tryToMakeLink()" name="q2">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected>Choose your model</option>
        <option value="8GB">8GB</option>
        <option value="16GB">16GB</option>
    </select>
     <h4>What color is your phone?</h4>

    <select style="margin-top: 1pt" onchange="tryToMakeLink()" name="q3">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected>Choose your model</option>
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <div id=linkDiv>
        <input type=button disabled=disabled value=Next />
    </div>
</form>
```

and

```
function tryToMakeLink() {
    //get all selected radios
    var q1 = document.querySelector('select[name="q1"]');
    var q2 = document.querySelector('select[name="q2"]');
    var q3 = document.querySelector('select[name="q3"]');

    //make sure the user has selected all 3
    if (q1 == null || q2 == null || q3 == null) {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button disabled=disabled value=Next>";
    } else {
        console.log(q1, q1.selectedIndex)

        //now we know we have 3 radios, so get their values
        q1 = q1.selectedIndex > 0 ? q1.options[q1.selectedIndex].value : '';
        q2 = q2.selectedIndex > 0 ? q2.options[q2.selectedIndex].value : '';
        q3 = q3.selectedIndex > 0 ? q3.options[q3.selectedIndex].value : '';

        //now check the values to display a different link for the desired configuration
        if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "Black") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://google.com/';\">att 8gb black</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "Other" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "White") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';\">other 8b white</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "White") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://bing.com/';\">another option</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "Black") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://gmail.com/';\">oops</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "White") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://hotmail.com/';\">can't</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "Other" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "Black") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://images.google.com/';\">yours</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "Other" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "White") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://youtube.com/';\">mines</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "Other" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "Black") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://docs.google.com/';\">what</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "Unlocked" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "White") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://wepriceit.webs.com/';\">red</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "Unlocked" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "Black") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://webs.com/';\">orange</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "Unlocked" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "White") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://gazelle.com/';\">green</input>";
        } else if (q1 == "Unlocked" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "Black") {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://glyde.com/';\">blue</input>";
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aYL8b/)

Answer (score 0):

When getting values from a `<select>`, you have to do a few things differently.

Change your HTML to use `onchange`, and give the `<select>` a `name` attribute, not its options.  Styling should take place outside of the markup.  Elements should also have unique IDs, or, in this case, no ID.

```
<select onchange="tryToMakeLink()" name='q1'>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected>Choose your model</option>
    <option value="AT&T">AT&T</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Unlocked">Unlocked</option>
</select>
```

Then, use your query selector to get the `<select>`:

```
var q1 = document.querySelector('select[name="q1"]');
```

Instead of checking for `null`, check for `selectedIndex`:

```
if (q1.selectedIndex && q2.selectedIndex && q3.selectedIndex) {
     ...enable button and proceed...
```

Then, use the `selectedIndex` to get the value of the option when you're ready.

```
q1 = q1.options[q1.selectedIndex];
```

Then proceed as usual.

Also, if you're going to send the user to a new page, good UX (user experience) practices dictate that you should use a LINK, because people will expect a link to change their browser.  If they click a button and go to a new page, that's less intuitive.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hPDCA/1/) with your code working for `ATT 8GB black`.  I've cleaned it up a bit though.

Comment: I've updated everything just like you said and it still doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/Yq8Qf/3/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<h4>What carrier do you have?</h4>
<select style="margin-top: 1pt" id="carrier">
    <option value="">Choose your carrier...</option>
    <option value="ATT">AT&#38;T</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Unlocked">Unlocked</option>
</select>
<h4>What is your phones capicity?</h4>
<select style="margin-top: 1pt" id="capacity">
    <option value="">Choose your capacity...</option>
    <option value="8">8GB</option>
    <option value="16">16GB</option>
</select>
<h4>What color is your phone?</h4>
<select style="margin-top: 1pt" id="color">
    <option value="">Choose your color...</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
</select>
<p>
    <input disabled id="mybutton" type="button" value="Next"/>
</p>
```

**Javascript**

Change the second drop-down in the pane from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`. I know I didn't use a perfect load event but this works for now. :p All of the URLs are stored in a JSON object so you can edit it more easily. Right now it just alerts with the URL selected.

```
var URLs = {
    'ATT': {
        '8': {
            'black': 'http://www.google.com/',
            'white': 'http://www.yahoo.com/'
        },
        '16': {
            'black': 'http://www.dogpile.com/',
            'white': 'http://www.bing.com/'
        }
    },
    'Other': {
        '8': {
            'black': 'http://www.google.com',
            'white': 'http://www.yahoo.com'
        },
        '16': {
            'black': 'http://www.dogpile.com/',
            'white': 'http://www.bing.com/'
        }
    },
    'Unlocked': {
        '8': {
            'black': 'http://www.google.com',
            'white': 'http://www.yahoo.com'
        },
        '16': {
            'black': 'http://www.dogpile.com/',
            'white': 'http://www.bing.com/'
        }
    }
};

// check to see if all selects have a value that isn't the first one
function checkInput() {
    var disable = false;
    var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for(var i=0,l=select.length;i<l;i++) {
        if(select[i].selectedIndex==0)
            { disable = true; }
    }
    document.getElementById('mybutton').disabled = disable;
}

function go() {
    var carrierE = document.getElementById('carrier');
    var carrier = carrierE.getElementsByTagName('option')[carrierE.selectedIndex].value;

    var capacityE = document.getElementById('capacity');
    var capacity = capacityE.getElementsByTagName('option')[capacityE.selectedIndex].value;

    var colorE = document.getElementById('color');
    var color = colorE.getElementsByTagName('option')[colorE.selectedIndex].value;

    window.alert(URLs[carrier][capacity][color]);
}

function init() {
    var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

//  attach checkInput to all select elements
    for(var i=0,l=select.length;i<l;i++) {
        if(select[i].addEventListener)
            { select[i].addEventListener('change',checkInput,false); }
        else if(select[i].attachEvent)
            { select[i].attachEvent('onchange',checkInput); }
        else
            { select[i].onchange = checkInput; }
    }

    var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');

    if(button.addEventListener)
        { button.addEventListener('click',go,false); }
    else if(button.attachEvent)
        { button.attachEvent('onclick',go); }
    else
        { button.onclick = go; }
}

if(document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init,false);
}
else {
//  I can do better but it's not important here
    window.onload = init;
}
```